# Resources for scripting vim with python

Tags: vimscript, plugin-system, vimscript-python

I love vim, I love python, and I dislike vimscript. So I would like to know how to write plugins (or throwaway scripts) for vim in python.

Of course, the first reference should be `:h python`, but I find it very hard to follow. A different reference might be to read the source for full-fledged vim plugins written (largely) in python, like [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips). But surely there are stepping stones in the middle?

Comment: Asking for resources isnt a question with a definitive answer. Like asking for a tutorial or a good book.

Comment: I would agree that I'm asking for a tutorial (or a good book were it only to exist). I wouldn't agree that it's a bad thing. I must admit that I'm colored by [math.se], which uses the [tag:reference-request] tag as a way to direct new learners towards good resources instead of being lost in the vast ocean of mediocrity that is the standard level of resources out there.

Comment: Treatment of this genre of questions [is being discussed on Meta](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/38/24).